# Gimp keeps on crashing with SIGSEGV error

Tags: snow-leopard, crash

I am trying out [Mac Gimp 2.8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimponosx/) as an alternative to Photoshop. I've been wanting to go for more OS stuff and wondered if Gimp would play nice. It seems both Photoshop and Gimp get the same error working with text. As soon as I try to work with my fonts in Gimp I get:

```
Process:         X11.bin [2865]
Path:            /Applications/Utilities/X11.app/Contents/MacOS/X11.bin
Identifier:      org.x.X11
Version:         2.3.6 (2.3.6)
Build Info:      X11server-850300~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  Xquartz [2864]

Date/Time:       2012-05-10 16:33:42.741 +0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          326391 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           18
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  2931240 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   8
Anonymous UUID:                      00AEB68B-72E9-4A9A-812A-B2C773A30E8D

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  2

Application Specific Information:
X.Org X Server 1.4.2-apple56 Build Date: 20100624

Thread 0:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83069d7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8306a3ed mach_msg + 59
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff81b5b902 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff81b5ad8f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
4   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff815697ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 333
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff815695f3 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 310
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff815694ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 59
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8978eeb2 _DPSNextEvent + 708
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8978e801 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8975468f -[NSApplication run] + 395
10  X11.bin                         0x0000000100007035 X11ApplicationMain + 1210
11  X11.bin                         0x000000010001136d server_main + 217
12  X11.bin                         0x000000010000180d do_start_x11_server + 321
13  X11.bin                         0x00000001000024e0 _Xstart_x11_server + 143
14  X11.bin                         0x0000000100002352 mach_startup_server + 106
15  libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff830e69a8 mach_msg_server + 357
16  X11.bin                         0x000000010000228b main + 1378
17  X11.bin                         0x0000000100001268 start + 52

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83082c0a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83084add _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff830847b4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff830842de _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83083c08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83083aa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2 Crashed:
0   X11.bin                         0x000000010001bc1b RootlessComposite + 129
1   X11.bin                         0x00000001000bab39 ProcRenderComposite + 374
2   X11.bin                         0x000000010005b781 Dispatch + 751
3   X11.bin                         0x0000000100069cac dix_main + 1309
4   X11.bin                         0x000000010001149e server_thread + 50
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff830a2fd6 _pthread_start + 331
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff830a2e89 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff83069d7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8306a3ed mach_msg + 59
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff81b5b902 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff81b5ad8f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff81b5ab16 CFRunLoopRun + 70
5   X11.bin                         0x0000000100020469 xpbproxy_run + 554
6   X11.bin                         0x0000000100007065 xpbproxy_x_thread + 9
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff830a2fd6 _pthread_start + 331
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff830a2e89 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff830a4a6a __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff830a8881 _pthread_cond_wait + 1286
2   X11.bin                         0x000000010000dcf7 DarwinProcessFDAdditionQueue_thread + 89
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff830a2fd6 _pthread_start + 331
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff830a2e89 thread_start + 13
```

The error I am getting using fonts in Adobe CS5 Photoshop is http://pastebin.com/pw9ZghGj and here a snippet:

```
Process:         Adobe Photoshop CS5 [4174]
Path:            /Applications/Adobe Photoshop CS5/Adobe Photoshop CS5.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Photoshop CS5
Identifier:      com.adobe.Photoshop
Version:         12.0.4 (12.0.4x20110407.r.1265) (12.0.4)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [422]

Date/Time:       2012-05-11 09:12:37.047 +0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          332574 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           19
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  73671 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   22
Anonymous UUID:                      00AEB68B-72E9-4A9A-812A-B2C773A30E8D

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007f7f70335814
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: release


Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff88003f0c objc_msgSend + 40
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff81bd6361 __CFRunArrayDeallocate + 321
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff81b1aa73 _CFRelease + 179
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff81b1aa73 _CFRelease + 179
4   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff815961bf TCoreTextEngine::Invalidate() + 31
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff81545472 TCoreTextEngine::Init(void const*, THIThemeTextInfo const*) + 60
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff815451e4 TThemeTextCache::Create(void const*, THIThemeTextInfo const*) + 198
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff81544cc6 DataEngine::GetTextDimensions(void const*, double, HIThemeTextInfo*, double*, double*, double*) + 356
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff81544b25 HIThemeGetTextDimensions + 158
9   com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000d13cf 0x100000000 + 857039
10  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000d15fc 0x100000000 + 857596
11  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000d16d8 0x100000000 + 857816
12  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000e405a 0x100000000 + 933978
13  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000dcc29 0x100000000 + 904233
14  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000dcd1d 0x100000000 + 904477
15  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000e8226 0x100000000 + 950822
16  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000c58f3 0x100000000 + 809203
17  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000c58f3 0x100000000 + 809203
18  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000c58f3 0x100000000 + 809203
19  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000c58f3 0x100000000 + 809203
20  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000c2fec 0x100000000 + 798700
21  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x00000001000bec72 0x100000000 + 781426
22  com.adobe.Photoshop             0x0000000100fb7894 AWS_CUI_GetVersionComments(OpaqueWindowPtr*, adobe::q::QDocument&, adobe::q::QString&, adobe::q::QAttributeList&, adobe::q::QDocument*, adobe::q::QProject*, long) + 13480952
```

Does anyone have any idea why Gimp is crashing here and how I can use it to add text layers again? I need to get some work done here and it just crashes as soon as I have selected a font and tried to add some text. I also wonder if the PS and Gimp errors are related.

<strike>I do have around 300 fonts installed. Macs and Gimp or Photoshop won't choke on that amount now will they..?!</strike>
When I load Gimp running onder Xquartz based on the MacPorts package after I added all the new fonts it did not crash. So this could be an Apple X11 issue or other Apple native code issue as Gimp 2.8 running under Apple's X11 naively is still crashing.

**Update**

Still no fix. Just got a new crash. See http://pastebin.com/i7DtHMVD . Again tried to edit text in Gimp and failed.

**Update 2**
Added latest Xquartz and upgraded OS to Lion. All is good now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same issue with Gimp. Installing quartz 2.7.1 and then a log out and back in to point at xquartz instead of Apple's x11 has helped.

The text tool now works for me on Gimp v2.8.

Comment: How would you make it point to Quartz 2.71? Is Photoshop crashing using fonts because of this X11 Apple issue as well?

Comment: I also have Gimp 2.6 on Xquartz 2.3.6 based on MacPorts and there I do not have any issues. So I guess Xquartz does help. I just wanted to run the latest version and MP does not have it yet. If Apple's X11 is really the issue here it might cause both Photoshop and Gimp 2.8 on Mac to crash. Would be great to kill to birds with one stone, but I doubt I can get Photoshop to use Xquartz instead of Apple's X11

Comment: Installed latest Xquartz and latest OSX Lion and now all good. You were right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[SIGSEGV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) is a signal that is sent from the operating system to a program notifying that it that is has accessed an invalid memory address. Since this is done by the program itself, there is really nothing that you a user can do to fix it. This is a bug in the software and someone familiar with the source code can probably easily fix it. I would suggest filing a bug report for the bug, if it hasn't already been filed, otherwise all you can do is sit and wait for it to be fixed.